# Open multiple files from file managers

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, file-manager

I've built a (Linux) GUI application that can be launched from a terminal and accepts an undefined number of files as arguments. The app reads sys.argv and lists the name of these files in a QListWidget.

The code is something like:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QCoreApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # parse command line arguments
        for i in QCoreApplication.argv()[1:]:
            ...

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
```

What I want to do is to be able to select multiple files from a file manager and open them with my app through the "Open with..." option provided by file managers. How this can be achieved?

With the current code, when I try it only one of the selected files is shown on the QListWidget.

Edit:

It finally seems that it depends to the file manager.
I tried with a few file managers and...

- pcmanfm: It only opens one of the selected files.
- spacefm: Works properly!
- dolphin: It opens each file to a different instance of my program. If
  I select 3 files it will open my app 3 times, one for each file.
- nautilus: I didn't manage to open any files with it. My program is not listed in the suggested applications and I didn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information to give a definite answer, but...

First, have you checked that a `print sys.argv` at the top of the code looks like you were expecting?

If so, does it work if you change the line...

```
for i in QCoreApplication.argv()[1:]:
```

...to...

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
```

For debugging purposes, you might also like to include the line...

```
assert QCoreApplication.argv()[1:] == sys.argv[1:]
```

...just before you start the for-loop.

Comment: No there's no difference between the two lists. I tried to print the sys.argv but I didn't know how, because the app was not running from a terminal and there was not stdout (?) (Okay, log file maybe will do). But it seems that I found the problem, I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Ilias95 If you do `sys.stdout = open('/tmp/logfile', 'w')` then all `print` statements will be redirected to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a QFileDialog: [Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html)

Comment: I do use one when program is open, but I want to achieve the above-described behaviour as well.